# what is the story behind the word 'Sky' meaning 'the most amazing girl you can ever meet'?

Tags: etymology, slang, phrase-origin

I researched this question on this site. I saw the word  sky used in a way I never heard if. I searched on google and saw these definitions on The Urban dictioney (https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sky) that include 
"the most amazing girl you can ever meet. She's nice, funny, undeniable, and caring. A great lover and friend. will put a smile in your face and make you laugh until you pee." (2010)

and "The perfect girl. Has wonderful stories, makes you laugh any chance she can, and is absolutely gorgeous. Sky is the perfect girl because she cares about you and how you feel. She is shy, yet social at the same time. She is beautiful, and it seems as though she is the only ray of light in this world of darkness. She is perfect." (2019)

And I never heard of this usage.

May I ask the story behind this usage. To narrow that down, I guess (1) the origin I(as close as close as possible) and (2) how widespread it is.

Thank

Comment: I'm guessing those "definitions" were contributed by someone named Sky. If I try really, really hard to be less cynical, I can concede that maybe they were contributed by someone whose girlfriend is named Sky. In either case, they're one-offs, not actual usage.

Comment: @Marthaª According to the definition page, it was contributed by LOVE4SKY so I will give them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: It also says `(This post goes out to my everything. Sky I love you with all my heart.)` seems like a declaration of love to me

Comment: Almost all of Urban Dictionary's definitions are jokes (read the whole "sky" page). If you want to know what a word really means, use a reputable dictionary such as Oxford, Cambridge, Merriam-Webster, etc. It's also a good idea to cross check dictionaries for the same meanings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a made up definition at Urban Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The story is that Urban Dictionary entries like this don't tell you anything about how a word is used.

That entry was probably written by somebody thinking of a person with the *given name* "Sky". Authors of Urban Dictionary entries often contribute in-jokes, personal compliments or insults, or just something they think is funny. The site is not a good source in general for definitions; it can be useful as a last result source for slang terms when no other source has any information, but for a frequent and well-known word like "sky", you'll get more junk if you check Urban Dictionary than if you check a mainstream online dictionary like Merriam-Webster or Dictionary.com.

You see the same thing on many other entries for names on Urban Dictionary:

- [David](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=David)

  > Most hilarious person you will ever meet. Sweet, kind, of course funny, and cute, although he might admit to none of those things.

  This is not a *definition* of "David". "David" does not mean these things, either as a word or as a name. It's just someone's opinion about some particular person named "David".
- [Andy](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Andy)

  > One who has a fiery temper and no tolerance for BS
  >   Who also keeps their emotions inside until needed then its a nuclear explosion.
  >   A good friend but will insult you if he feels like it.

  Likewise, this is not a definition of "Andy". "Andy" is not a word used to refer to someone who has a fiery temper. Whoever wrote this entry just knew someone called "Andy" and wanted to write something about that person.

Just check other name entries and you'll see similar nonsense that isn't actually dictionary material. I think that in most cases, people were thinking of particular friends or acquaintances that they knew with the names, but in some cases, people might have some stereotypical association with the name itself. (Another possibility brought up in the Urban Dictionary entries for "[name](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Name)" and "[Urban Dictionary names](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Urban%20Dictionary%20Names)" is that some people write flattering definitions of their own names.) Unfortunately, there is no way to tell which of these explanations applies to an Urban Dictionary name entry. They're unlikely to be helpful to you either way, so I advise ignoring them.